# Trying to convert a file that lists a single IP address to that addresses class C network range

Tags: python-3.x

Here's the function i created:

```
def convert(inc_ip):
    ip_address = inc_ip

    ip_parts = ip_address.split('.')
    ip_copy = ip_parts.copy()
    ip_list = [ip_parts[0], ip_parts[1], ip_parts[2], ip_parts[3]]
    ip_list[3] = '1'
    ip_list_copy = [ip_copy[0], ip_copy[1], ip_copy[2], ip_copy[3]]
    ip_list_copy[3] = '254'
    join = '.'
    ip_join = join.join(ip_list)
    ip_join_copy = join.join(ip_list_copy)
    ip_range = (str(ip_join) + '-' + str(ip_join_copy))

    print("-" * 30, 'ip_adddress', "-" * 27)
    print(ip_address)

    print("-" * 30, 'ip_range', "-" * 30)
    print(ip_range)
```

And here's what i've written to try and achieve the goal:

```
with open('ip address.txt', 'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.read().split('/n')
    for line in lines:
        inc_ip = line
        convert(inc_ip)
    print(lines)
```

The output is a step in the right direction but isn't quite there:

```
------------------------------ ip_range ------------------------------
10.0.0.1-10.0.0.254
['10.0.0.0\n10.0.12.0
```

I'm trying to convert all the ip addresses listed (about 300) in either the output of pycharm or a saved to a text file

How would i go about fixing this?

Comment: One issue is that you are splitting on "/n" instead of "\n"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace "/n" to "\n", that the reason why you split is not working.
So like this :

`with open('ip address.txt', 'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.read().split('/n')
    for line in lines:
        inc_ip = line
        convert(inc_ip)
    print(lines)`

This is giving me this output :

------------------------------ ip_adddress ---------------------------

10.0.0.0

------------------------------ ip_range ------------------------------

10.0.0.1-10.0.0.254

------------------------------ ip_adddress ---------------------------

10.0.12.0

------------------------------ ip_range ------------------------------

10.0.12.1-10.0.12.254
['10.0.0.0', '10.0.12.0']

Note : I suggest for future post to explain more what you are trying to achieved, and when you are using a file such as ip address.txt, that you post what it contains to help user to reply